# Performance difference with unpacking

Tags: haskell

I'm using GHC 8.0.1.
I've written simple matrix multiplication benchmark where I try two different approaches for matrix datatype:

1) Matrix contains 4 vector of 4 float elements.

2) Matrix contains 16 float elements.

I suppose theses two should be identical because in first case vectors will be unpacked into matrix datatype. And indeed when I look into generated Core, it seems to be the case. Moreover, Core for `mult` functions seems to be identical.

Nevertheless, second version runs 2 times slower than the first one.

**main.hs:**

```
module Main where

import Criterion.Main
import Control.Monad
import System.Random.MWC
import qualified MatMul.Unrolled as U
import qualified MatMul.UnrolledFull as F

main :: IO ()
main = do
    gen <- create
    elems1 <- mkElems gen
    elems2 <- mkElems gen

    defaultMain
        [ bgroup "matrix mult 4x4"
            [ bench "unrolled"     $ nf (U.mult (U.mkMat elems1)) (U.mkMat elems2)
            , bench "unrolledFull" $ nf (F.mult (F.mkMat elems1)) (F.mkMat elems2) ]
        ]
    where
        -- see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.5.0/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#v:uniform
        mkElems gen = replicateM 16 (fmap (\x -> x - (2 :: Float) ^^ (-33 :: Int)) (uniform gen :: IO Float))
```

**unrolled.hs:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}

module MatMul.Unrolled where

import Control.DeepSeq
import GHC.Generics

data Vector4f = Vector4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    deriving (Show, Eq, Generic, NFData)

data Matrix4x4f = Matrix4x4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Vector4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Vector4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Vector4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Vector4f             
    deriving (Show, Eq, Generic, NFData)

mkMat :: [Float] -> Matrix4x4f
mkMat (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l:m:n:o:p:_) = 
    Matrix4x4f
        (Vector4f a b c d)
        (Vector4f e f g h)
        (Vector4f i j k l)
        (Vector4f m n o p)

mult :: Matrix4x4f -> Matrix4x4f -> Matrix4x4f
mult
    (Matrix4x4f 
        (Vector4f a0 a1 a2 a3)
        (Vector4f b0 b1 b2 b3)
        (Vector4f c0 c1 c2 c3)
        (Vector4f d0 d1 d2 d3))
    (Matrix4x4f 
        (Vector4f x0 x1 x2 x3)
        (Vector4f y0 y1 y2 y3)
        (Vector4f z0 z1 z2 z3)
        (Vector4f w0 w1 w2 w3)) =
    Matrix4x4f 
        (Vector4f (a0*x0+a1*y0+a2*z0+a3*w0) (a0*x1+a1*y1+a2*z1+a3*w1) (a0*x2+a1*y2+a2*z2+a3*w2) (a0*x3+a1*y3+a2*z3+a3*w3))
        (Vector4f (b0*x0+b1*y0+b2*z0+b3*w0) (b0*x1+b1*y1+b2*z1+b3*w1) (b0*x2+b1*y2+b2*z2+b3*w2) (b0*x3+b1*y3+b2*z3+b3*w3))
        (Vector4f (c0*x0+c1*y0+c2*z0+c3*w0) (c0*x1+c1*y1+c2*z1+c3*w1) (c0*x2+c1*y2+c2*z2+c3*w2) (c0*x3+c1*y3+c2*z3+c3*w3))
        (Vector4f (d0*x0+d1*y0+d2*z0+d3*w0) (d0*x1+d1*y1+d2*z1+d3*w1) (d0*x2+d1*y2+d2*z2+d3*w2) (d0*x3+d1*y3+d2*z3+d3*w3))
```

**unrolledFull.hs:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}

module MatMul.UnrolledFull where

import Control.DeepSeq
import GHC.Generics

data Matrix4x4f = Matrix4x4f
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Float
    deriving (Show, Eq, Generic, NFData)

mkMat :: [Float] -> Matrix4x4f
mkMat (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l:m:n:o:p:_) =
    Matrix4x4f a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p

mult :: Matrix4x4f -> Matrix4x4f -> Matrix4x4f
mult
    (Matrix4x4f a0 a1 a2 a3 b0 b1 b2 b3 c0 c1 c2 c3 d0 d1 d2 d3)
    (Matrix4x4f x0 x1 x2 x3 y0 y1 y2 y3 z0 z1 z2 z3 w0 w1 w2 w3) =
    Matrix4x4f 
        (a0*x0+a1*y0+a2*z0+a3*w0) (a0*x1+a1*y1+a2*z1+a3*w1) (a0*x2+a1*y2+a2*z2+a3*w2) (a0*x3+a1*y3+a2*z3+a3*w3)
        (b0*x0+b1*y0+b2*z0+b3*w0) (b0*x1+b1*y1+b2*z1+b3*w1) (b0*x2+b1*y2+b2*z2+b3*w2) (b0*x3+b1*y3+b2*z3+b3*w3)
        (c0*x0+c1*y0+c2*z0+c3*w0) (c0*x1+c1*y1+c2*z1+c3*w1) (c0*x2+c1*y2+c2*z2+c3*w2) (c0*x3+c1*y3+c2*z3+c3*w3)
        (d0*x0+d1*y0+d2*z0+d3*w0) (d0*x1+d1*y1+d2*z1+d3*w1) (d0*x2+d1*y2+d2*z2+d3*w2) (d0*x3+d1*y3+d2*z3+d3*w3)
```

I get following results:

```
Running 1 benchmarks...
Benchmark matMul: RUNNING...
benchmarking matrix mult 4x4/unrolled
time                 60.32 ns   (60.21 ns .. 60.43 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 60.40 ns   (60.28 ns .. 60.55 ns)
std dev              457.6 ps   (352.8 ps .. 612.8 ps)

benchmarking matrix mult 4x4/unrolledFull
time                 137.6 ns   (137.4 ns .. 137.8 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 137.7 ns   (137.5 ns .. 138.0 ns)
std dev              874.8 ps   (665.5 ps .. 1.194 ns)

Benchmark matMul: FINISH
```

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with the derived `NFData` instance. If I use `whnf` instead of `nf` (you only need to weak headed since the type is strict anyway), or write your own `NFData` instance, I get the same times for both.